# "Read the values of a and b" vs. "read the values a and b"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> - Read the values of a and b.
> - Read the values a and b.

The context is programming. Do I need to use *of*? What is the rule to use *of* before variables?

Comment: Why do you believe it makes any difference whether *a* and *b* are variables?

Comment: Can you give a full sentence (or paragraph) of context?

Answer (score 1):

According to the wikipedia article called “[Variable (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29)”,

> In computer programming, a variable is a storage location and an associated symbolic name (an identifier) which contains some known or unknown quantity or information, a value. The variable name is the usual way to reference the stored value; this separation of name and content allows the name to be used independently of the exact information it represents. The identifier in computer source code can be bound to a value during run time, and the value of the variable may thus change during the course of program execution.

Clearly, the above distinguishes between the name of a variable and the value of a variable.  Someone being precise about that distinction might say “the value of the variable named *b*” rather than saying “the value *b*” [which is a phrase they might reserve for the identifier *b* or for some constant value called *b*].  In slightly relaxed terminology, “the value of *b*” is an abbreviated form of “the value of a variable named *b*”.

Of course some people don't bother with these distinctions; they instead equate “the value **of** *b*” with “the value *b*”, even in cases where it is easy to use more-accurate terminology like “the variable *b*”.  That is, although you aren't likely to get in trouble for saying “the value *b*”, it is reasonable to include the word *of* or to refer to “the variable *b*”.